# Copy Filename and append another file using batch file

Tags: batch-file

OK, so I have been looking around for a way to copy from 1 filename and append to many other files

I know I'm suppose to have a script to show to get help with it, but I can't seem to find a good page that can get me close enough to test

This is what I have 
New Folder 1

```
Japan Buildings.jpeg
(1).txt
(2).txt
```

New Folder 2

```
China Buildings.jpeg
(1).txt
(2).txt
```

I want to add the file name from the jpeg to the other files 
this is the end result 
New Folder 1

```
Japan Buildings.jpeg
(1) Japan Buildings.txt
(2) Japan Buildings.txt
```

New Folder 2

```
China Buildings.jpeg
(1) China Buildings.txt
(2) China Buildings.txt
```

I have many folders with subfolders, so I'm looking for a batch file that can do this to over thousands of files

Can someone lead me to the right page, or help me get started with this. 
I have been looking on google and I can't find anything close

Thank you

Comment: What's the reason to rename all Japanese files to `(1)...`, while keeping the numbering for the Chinese files?

Comment: well each (#) has its own context, data, and when I made the files I was only putting (1).txt and 2.txt, and I was placing them in a folder called Chinese, but I have decided to rename the files (?) China, or Tokyo, so better to keep track of the files and not to overwrite them with others, as I have done before, but now I have to many files and folders, so to go one by one and manually right click and edit will be a nightmare, I need something that can read 1 .jpeg file name and append to the files within the folders, after this is done, I will be doing it manually with the right click paste

Comment: Sorry the (1) repeated was a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each subfolder matching `New folder*` get the base <jpegname> of the `jpeg` (assuming there is just one) and construct the source (`drive\path\(*).txt`) and destination (`(*) <jpegname>.txt` for the `ren` command:

```
for /d %%D in ("New Folder*") do (
  for %%F in ("%%D\*.jpeg") do (
    ren "%%~dpF(*).txt" "(*) %%~nF.*"
  )
)
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH - this worked great, now I will try to make it a sub Folder reader - since I have many folders and sub folders - your the BEST